# .NET C# Task await download file from AWS

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

I'm working on a script that downloads a ~100mb file from an AWS bucket, and want to wait for it to finish before continuing.
Using https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/dotnetv3/S3/scenarios/TransferUtilityBasics/TransferUtilityBasics/TransferMethods.cs
this script, I have the following code as my function:

```
public static async Task<string> DownloadAWSFile(string fileName, string filePath)
        {
            TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
            var success = await TransferMethods.DownloadSingleFileAsync(fileTransferUtility, Config.AWS_BucketName, fileName, filePath);
            if (success)
            {
                return "done";
            }
            else
            {
                return "error";
            }
        }
```

Which is called by this code:

```
Task<string> task = AWSGET.DownloadAWSFile("filetodownload.zip", "C:\\path\\to\\download\\");
            task.Wait();
            if (task.Result == "done")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Done Downloading", "Configuration", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error", "Configuration", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            }
```

the download code works fine on its own. I click the button that runs the AWSGET.DOwnloadAWSFile function, it works fine.
Once I had that working, I changed that function to a task, as shown above.
Now, it runs, it does the download, but it doesnt trigger anything - the alerts in this case - when its done, and it freezes up my program.

Any advice you can offer is appreciated. Still pretty new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```cs
task.Wait();
```

You should not use blocking waits on async code, because it can lead to deadlocks (which you are experiencing, check out [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) by Stephen Cleary). The best approach is just to `await` the task:

```cs
var result = await AWSGET.DownloadAWSFile(...);
```

Also possibly you should consider using `ConfigureAwait(false)` inside the download method, JIC:

```cs
var success = await TransferMethods.DownloadSingleFileAsync(...).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'll read that link, and make the suggested changes and see how it does. Appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly, and I learned a lot from that article, and will be reading more of his articles.